# Show that a graph with 9 vertices has at least five vertices of degree 6, or at least six vertices of degree 5.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with nine vertices, such that each vertex has degree $5$ or $6$. Show that $G$ has at least five vertices of degree $6$, or at least six vertices of degree $5$.

My friend and I have been working on this question for the past two days and we have nothing. Any pointers or help?

Comment: If neither of those things are true, $G$ has exactly $5$ vertices of degree $5$ and exactly $4$ vertices of degree $6$. Can you see why this is impossible?

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you. Both to Micah and Hagen.

Comment: @Micah I have the same problem at the moment but i didn't understand your hint, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji: Do you mean you don't understand why my hint is true, or you don't understand why it helps do the problem?

Comment: @Micah Why and how it helps to solve the problem

Comment: If $G$ does not have at least 5 vertices of degree 6, it has at most 4 vertices of degree 6. If $G$ does not have at least six vertices of degree 5, it has at most 5 vertices of degree 5. If it doesn't have exactly the maximum number in both cases, it doesn't have enough vertices (you know it has nine).

Comment: For how it helps, look at Hagen's hint.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* The sum of all vertex degrees is *twice* the number of edges.